# Erro post no swift com alamofire

Tags: ios, web-service, swift, post, alamofire

mas uma vez venho pedir auxilio a vocês.
Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em Swift utilizando web service escrito em java hospedado na Amazon AWS.

Quando eu tento realizar um cadastro via post o cadastro não é realizado.
O erro que me retorna é o seguinte

```
  FAILURE: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.} 
FAILURE
```

trecho do código do cadastro

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: usuario, encoding: .JSON, headers: nil).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in

                if response.result.isSuccess{

                    //self.geraAlerta("Sucesso", mensagem: "Cadastro realizado com Sucesso")
                 self.populaUsuario()
                 self.performSegueWithIdentifier("cadastroTelaPrincipal", sender: self)


                }else{
                    print(response.description,"<-------")
                    self.geraAlerta("Falha", mensagem: "Não foi possível completar o cadastro, tente novamente mais tarde!")
                }
                self.btnCadastrar.userInteractionEnabled = true 
                print(response.result)
                print(response.result.value)
            })
```

Código no web service

```
@POST
@Path("/inserir")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void insereUsuario(Usuario usuario) {

    if (usuario != null) {
        try {
            usuario.setFotoByte(Util.converteToByte(usuario.getFoto()));
            usuario.setDataCadastro(new Date());

            new UsuarioDAO().inseirUsuario(usuario);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Alguém ai poderia me informar como resolver esse problema?

Se eu tentar acessar a url direto pelo browser me retorna 405

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25986715/2303865

Answer (score 0):

```
 FAILURE: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.} 
FAILURE
```

Esse erro significa que você está passando errado seus parâmetros, o seu JSON (NSDictionary) está inválido.

Verifique como está seu parâmetro e como você está esperando esse JSON na sua API.
Como está o seu "usuário" que você está passando como parâmetro? Se ainda estiver com dúvidas, dê um print(usuario) para analizarmos :)